# Get the current page custom taxonomy use to query custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy, custom-wordpress-pages

So far I have a custom taxonomy that is registered called `position` that is associated with a specific page as well a custom post type called `People`. I also have a page that has the custom taxonomy set to use the `position` taxonomy as well.

What I am trying to do is get it so that I can query the custom post type of `People` to show a list of entries with the custom taxonomy that is set on the page as well as the post type.

For example, the taxonomy of `position` has some items assigned to it, e.g. - Sales, Accounting, etc. I have some entries for the custom post type of `People` e.g. - John, Mary, Sam, etc. I have John and Mary set to use the taxonomy of `Sales`, in this case.

On the page of Sales, I have it set to use the custom `position` taxonomy of `Sales`.

What I'm trying to get is get the custom taxonomy of `position` on the Sales template page which should return the name and/or slug of `Sales` and then take that info and pass it into a query to check against the `People` custom post type and pull the associated people from that custom taxonomy. In this case, on the Sales page it should be able to pull the two people of John and Mary.

So far I have this on the Sales template page:

```
<?php $tax = get_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => 'position' ) ); ?>
```

That gives me the array of the terms but how do I get the name of the associated taxonomy name that is set on the page and then pass that to a query to get the people?

Looks like if I use `get_terms` it gives me **everything** and just need the one set taxonomy that is for that particular page, assign that to a variable and then use it for a query like this:

```
<?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'people', 'taxonomy' => $tax);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
```

Comment: Look at get_the_terms() if you want to get terms of the current page. Otherwise I’d recommend you make a shortcode which accepts one variable, maybe like this: [get_people_by_job position=“sales”] might make what you are doing more flexible. When this is called, make it do a wp_query for post-type people, with the taxonomy/term passed from the shortcode. Take a look at wp_query, its one of the most common things you’ll have to do in wordrpress php programming. https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: Thanks @CarlF.Corneil! I got it figured out and posted my update below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I got it figured out eventually.

In order to make this work you'd need to get the current post ID from the page, pass that through `get_the_terms` and then construct a query to query the custom post type with `tax_query` and then pass that into the `tax_query` array:

```
<?php
            $id = get_post($post->ID);
            $tax = get_the_terms($id, 'position');
            $args = array(
              'post_type' => 'people',
              'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                  'taxonomy' => 'position',
                  'field'    => 'slug',
                  'terms'    => $tax[0]->slug,
                ),
              ),
            );
            $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
            ?>
```

That will cross reference the custom taxonomy between the current page and the custom post types and will get those post types that are assigned with the specific taxonomy (in this case, Sales).

Hope this helps!